# Xamarin - Deploy IOS app for beta testers

Tags: ios, xamarin, testing, deployment, beta

I'm developing my first app and have a bunch of beta testers. some for Android, some for IOS.

Android, no problem at all.. Deploy the app ad-hoc and share it with them. But for the IOS version its driving me crazy.

If i want to make a Developement Provisioning profile it asks for the Iphones to associate with it... But my testers are around the globe.. Is there a way to make a simple package, that they can download and install, by accepting some security warnings, and test right away?

Comment: You can use either Apple's TestFlight or MS appcenter.ms to deploy to testers.  Both services will help the user register their device for testing.

Comment: @Jason thanks, but if I have to specify what devices can test it, will i have to rebuild it each time somebody registers the device for testing?

Comment: Well, how do I put it if you add more UUID's then YES! For more information : https://www.raywenderlich.com/5352-testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apple's public test , when you upload build to ITunes Connect , you can make public test after Apple Reviews it [Public Link test](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09262018a)
You must at one point create group for testers, then upload build and submit for review, after that you can get public link like in picture below
[image]